# How do I show two Bokeh objects at once?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh vbar with RangeTool. I tried many different lines of code but this is still not working. I don't understand the error with 'browser'

The same code work with line or scatter

This is the error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'Figure' is not iterable

This is the code below:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Range1d

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
wdth = [0.5 for x in range(0,8)]
top = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

sourceRT5 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, width=wdth, top=top))
p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, 
           tools="", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="linear")


p.vbar('x', 'width', 'top', bottom=0, line_color='dodgerblue', 
       fill_color="dodgerblue", legend='New Words',
        source=sourceRT5)

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'

select = figure(plot_height=50, plot_width=800, y_range=(0,10),
                x_axis_type="linear",  y_axis_type=None,
                tools="", toolbar_location=None)

range_rool = RangeTool(x_range=Range1d(3,8))
range_rool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_rool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.vbar('x', 'width', 'top', source=sourceRT5)
select.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_rool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_rool

show(p,select)
```

More on the error:

```
File "FromInt.py", line 6433, in testrangeVBar
    show(p,select)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io/showing.py", line 137, in show
    return _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new, notebook_handle=notebook_handle)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io/showing.py", line 165, in _show_with_state
  controller = get_browser_controller(browser=browser)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/util/browser.py", line 47, in get_browser_controller
  controller = webbrowser.get(browser)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/webbrowser.py", line 34, in get
    if '%s' in browser:
TypeError: argument of type 'Figure' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to display multiple figures. [`show`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.show) takes a single object which it should display, the second argument is which browser it is supposed to use for that (e.g. firefox, chrome, IE, vivaldi, ...). While you wrote it worked with scatter I guess that it did not throw an error but did not actually work.

Bokeh has some [documentation on displaying multiple plots](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html). Short version is you need to tell it in which way it should layout it. A very general function is [`layout`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html#bokeh.layouts.layout) :

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
... # your code without show(...)
show(layout([p,select]))
```

Comment: you are right, my scatter example did have: show(column([p,select])) with column part of bokeh.layouts